# python dredd hook

Tags: python, api, swagger

Есть файл, где прописанно описание API

**test.yaml**

```
swagger: '2.0'
info:
  description: Api Documentation
  version: '1.0'
  title: Api Documentation
  termsOfService: urn:tos
  contact: {}
  license:
    name: Apache 2.0
    url: http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
host: xxx
consumes:
- application/json;charset=utf-8
produces:
- application/json
basePath: "/network-management"
schemes:
- https
paths:
  "/network":
    x-summary: "Networks"
    get:
      summary: "All"
      produces:
      - application/json;charset=utf-8
      responses:
        '200':
          description: Ok 
          schema:
            "$ref": "#/definitions/NetworkResponse"
    post:
      summary: "Publish new network"
      produces:
        - application/json;charset=utf-8
      parameters:
      - name: id
        in : body
        required: true
        description: id
        schema: 
          "$ref": "#/definitions/NetworkPostRequest"
      responses:
        '200':
          description: Ok
          schema:
            "$ref": "#/definitions/NetworkIdResponse"
```

POST вызов создаёт сеть и выбрасывает ответ вида:

```
{
"id": "net-123456789",
"address": "x.x.x.x/xx",
"cidr": "/xx",
 "name": "xxnamexxx"
}
```

Пытаюсь написать dredd hook , который после создания сети в POST запросе возьмёт этот `id` и передаст его дальше в запросы типа GET/PUT и так далее.

Пытаюсь так:

```py
import json
import dredd_hooks as hooks

response_stash = {}

@hooks.after("Networks > Publish new network > 200 > application/json;charset=utf-8")
def save_network_id_to_stash(transaction):
    # save HTTP response with ID to the stash
    response_stash[transaction['Api Documentation > Networks > Publish new network > id ']] = transaction['200 > application/json;charset=utf-8']

@hooks.before("Network with ID > Get network with ID > 200 > application/json;charset=utf-8")
def add_network_id_to_request(transaction):
    parsed_body = json.loads(response_stash['Networks > Publish new network > 200 > application/json;charset=utf-8'])
    network_id = parsed_body['POST (200) /networks']
    transaction['$host/net-11e477a1716bff'] = transaction['$host/net-11e477a1716bff'].replace('net-11e477a1716bff', network_id)
```

Получаю ошибку KeyError в строкe

```
response_stash[transaction['Api Documentation > Networks > Publish new network > id ']] = transaction['200 > application/json;charset=utf-8']
```

Смотрел dredd data structure , но где-то делаю ошибку в объявлении. 
Как правильно объявить переменные `transaction['name']` и `transaction['real']`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашёл ответ.

Можно объявлять в неявном виде типа `transaction['name']`. 
dredd примет значения сам из транзакций. KeyError может возникнуть из-за не правильной навигации по JSON.

```
parsed_body = json.loads(response_stash['Networks > Publish new network > 200 > application/json;charset=utf-8']['body'])
```

решило вопрос.

Деббажить можно через `print(transaction)` и смотреть какие данные отдаёт dredd